# Center views in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So firstly yes there are similar posts on here and i haven't been able to solve my issue reading them. I need to center two buttons in a constraint layout as shown below.

[image]

The buttons sit below a few labels as you will be able to see in the xml at the end. Currently the resulting layout looks like this.

[image]

The result i am after is like in the first image, so the two buttons should be centred under the text view with "No Location" in it.

I am fairly new to using constraint layouts. I read using "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" was the best approach but i have had no luck with it. The xml for my layout is below, any help or guidance is much appreciated.

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkIn_layout">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkIn_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Manual Check-in"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkIn_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_title" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkIn_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_location"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="Glow New Media"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_duration" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkIn_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check Out"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/RoundedButton"
            android:textColor="#399AEA"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/onduty_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_location"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/onduty_button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_power"
        android:background="@drawable/PowerButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_location"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/checkIn_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add RighttoRight to parent for powerbutton and remove the horizontalBias in both Roundbutton and powerbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only one set; either **left-right**, or **start,end**. Now to achieve what you are trying is exactly what `chainStyle` does. Check out the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#developer-guide) for reference(See chain concepts from the link).

What you need is `packed` as horizontalChainStyle.

You can do it like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/checkIn_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
tools:background="@color/blue">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/checkIn_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Manual Check-in"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/checkIn_duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/checkIn_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Glow New Media"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_duration" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkIn_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:text="Check Out"
    android:textColor="#399AEA"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/onduty_button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_location" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/onduty_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkIn_button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkIn_location" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I had read about the chains but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Also if you use both left-right and start-end, many times even though you've done it right, it won't work. So, keep a track that you use only either of them.

Comment: [This](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) helps explains chains very well.